# Multiple PHP versions on one Digital Ocean droplet

Tags: php, apache2, virtualhost

Is there an easy way of using multiple php versions on one single digital ocean droplet. Basically, I want something like what we have for cPanel (https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/MultiPHP+Manager+for+cPanel) where we can select different php versions for different apacha virtual hosts/websites hosted on the same linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider PHPBrew:

https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew

There's an overview here of the process:

http://www.sivaschenko.com/multiple-php-versions-simultaneously-apache/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way like we have in cPanel. cPanel basically uses its own RPM of PHPs to Manage/Maintain PHP versions. Digital Ocean droplet comes with predefined images of various distros, so you will need to manually install versions and use them for our virtual hosts.